Android Automotive not launch
Error log1: Watchdog service is not initialized.
Failed to fetch package infos from car watchdog service: Watchdog service is not initialized
Error log2:Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gcar_x86_64/emulator_car64_x86_64:13/TAG1.230812.001.D2/11755969:userdebug/dev-keys' 2024-05-21 21:20:32.890 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A Revision: '0' 2024-05-21 21:20:32.890 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A ABI: 'x86_64' 2024-05-21 21:20:32.890 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A Timestamp: 2024-05-21 21:20:32.855032600+0700 2024-05-21 21:20:32.890 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A Process uptime: 0s 2024-05-21 21:20:32.890 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A Cmdline: /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.audio.service-caremu 2024-05-21 21:20:32.890 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A pid: 3676, tid: 3678, name: HwBinder:3676_2 >>> /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.audio.service-caremu <<< 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A uid: 1041 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x000000000000002c 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A Cause: null pointer dereference 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A rax 0000000000000000 rbx ffffffffffffffff rcx 000000000000002c rdx 000000000000000c 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A r8 0000000000000000 r9 0000000000000000 r10 0000000000000015 r11 0000000000000000 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A r12 00000000ffffffff r13 0000000000000000 r14 000000000000002c r15 00007e2b657249b0 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A rdi 000000000000002c rsi ffffffffffffffff 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A rbp 0000000000000000 rsp 00007e2b657246d8 rip 00007e2df6ef6981 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A backtrace: 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #00 pc 0000000000055981 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (strlen+17) (BuildId: f090904cc3ac285a6f190f8003c3eb0e) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #01 pc 000000000008bec8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__strlen_chk+8) (BuildId: f090904cc3ac285a6f190f8003c3eb0e) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #02 pc 00000000000a65a9 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__vfprintf+5721) (BuildId: f090904cc3ac285a6f190f8003c3eb0e) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #03 pc 00000000000c7433 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (vsnprintf+259) (BuildId: f090904cc3ac285a6f190f8003c3eb0e) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #04 pc 00000000000098ad /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_print+221) (BuildId: 6b890ed51b66670f87b252ab8bb0baf6) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #05 pc 0000000000004a25 /vendor/lib64/hw/audio.primary.caremu.so (adev_open+725) (BuildId: 3e9318f427a2f3e3753e17aa22817e38) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #06 pc 000000000001f650 /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.audio@6.0-impl.so (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::implementation::DevicesFactory::loadAudioInterface(char const*, audio_hw_device**)+112) (BuildId: 4f835e19d5b9de4830fb92b8455dd749) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #07 pc 000000000001f45d /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.audio@6.0-impl.so (android::hardware::Return android::hardware::audio::V6_0::implementation::DevicesFactory::openDevice<android::hardware::audio::V6_0::implementation::PrimaryDevice, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::Result, android::spandroid::hardware::audio::V6_0::IPrimaryDevice const&)> >(char const*, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::Result, android::spandroid::hardware::audio::V6_0::IPrimaryDevice const&)>)+61) (BuildId: 4f835e19d5b9de4830fb92b8455dd749) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #08 pc 000000000001f3d8 /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.audio@6.0-impl.so (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::implementation::DevicesFactory::openPrimaryDevice(std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::Result, android::spandroid::hardware::audio::V6_0::IPrimaryDevice const&)>)+104) (BuildId: 4f835e19d5b9de4830fb92b8455dd749) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #09 pc 000000000006d55e /vendor/lib64/android.hardware.audio@6.0.so (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::BnHwDevicesFactory::_hidl_openPrimaryDevice(android::hidl::base::V1_0::BnHwBase*, android::hardware::Parcel const&, android::hardware::Parcel*, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::Parcel&)>)+286) (BuildId: 11c6b9718d25695de7043d7451d9add2) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #10 pc 000000000006d8a5 /vendor/lib64/android.hardware.audio@6.0.so (android::hardware::audio::V6_0::BnHwDevicesFactory::onTransact(unsigned int, android::hardware::Parcel const&, android::hardware::Parcel*, unsigned int, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::Parcel&)>)+325) (BuildId: 11c6b9718d25695de7043d7451d9add2) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #11 pc 00000000000b747f /apex/com.android.vndk.v33/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::BHwBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::hardware::Parcel const&, android::hardware::Parcel*, unsigned int, std::__1::function<void (android::hardware::Parcel&)>)+127) (BuildId: 47fbb26f8180cd86cda3e558439fa1c8) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.892 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #12 pc 0000000000072090 /apex/com.android.vndk.v33/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+1152) (BuildId: 47fbb26f8180cd86cda3e558439fa1c8) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.893 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #13 pc 000000000007017d /apex/com.android.vndk.v33/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+445) (BuildId: 47fbb26f8180cd86cda3e558439fa1c8) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.893 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #14 pc 000000000006ffb7 /apex/com.android.vndk.v33/lib64/libhidlbase.so (android::hardware::PoolThread::threadLoop()+23) (BuildId: 47fbb26f8180cd86cda3e558439fa1c8) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.893 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #15 pc 000000000001377f /apex/com.android.vndk.v33/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+175) (BuildId: 40deb5f170fc0918cea0b755da13ab08) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.893 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #16 pc 00000000000ccd9a /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+58) (BuildId: f090904cc3ac285a6f190f8003c3eb0e) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.893 3690-3690 DEBUG pid-3690 A #17 pc 0000000000060d47 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+55) (BuildId: f090904cc3ac285a6f190f8003c3eb0e) 2024-05-21 21:20:32.895 3690-3690 crash_dump64 pid-3690 E unable to connect to activity manager: No such file or directory 2024-05-21 21:20:32.895 301-301 tombstoned tombstoned E Tombstone written to: tombstone_04 2024-05-21 21:20:32.895 3305-3386 NativeTombstoneManager system_process E Tombstone's UID (1041) not an app, ignoring 2024-05-21 21:20:32.896 3305-3386 NativeTombstoneManager system_process E Tombstone's UID (1041) not an app, ignoring 2024-05-21 21:20:32.900 3675-3675 AudioFlinger pid-3675 E loadHwModule() error -2147483646 loading module primary 2024-05-21 21:20:32.900 3675-3675 AudioFlinger pid-3675 E loadHwModule() error -2147483646 loading module usb 2024-05-21 21:20:32.901 3675-3675 AudioFlinger pid-3675 E loadHwModule() error -2147483646 loading module r_submix 2024-05-21 21:20:32.903 3675-3680 HalDeathHandler pid-3675 E HAL server crashed, audio server is restarting 2024-05-21 21:20:32.891 0-0 init kernel E process with updatable components 'vendor.audio-hal' exited 4 times before boot completed 2024-05-21 21:20:32.896 0-0 init kernel E process with updatable components 'audioserver' exited 4 times before boot completed 2024-05-21 21:20:33.221 232-384 carwatchdogd carwatchdogd E Failed to fetch package infos from car watchdog service: Watchdog service is not initialized 2024-05-21 21:20:34.220 232-384 carwatchdogd carwatchdogd E Failed to fetch package infos from car watchdog service: Watchdog service is not initialized 2024-05-21 21:20:35.226 232-384 carwatchdogd carwatchdogd E Failed to fetch package infos from car watchdog service: Watchdog service is not initialized 2024-05-21 21:20:36.197 232-384 carwatchdogd carwatchdogd E Failed to fetch package infos from car watchdog service: Watchdog service is not initialized 2024-05-21 21:20:37.210 232-384 carwatchdogd carwatchdogd E Failed to fetch package infos from car watchdog service: Watchdog service is not initialized 2024-05-21 21:20:37.859 3699-3701 libc pid-3699 A Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2c in tid 3701 (HwBinder:3699_2), pid 3699 (audio.service-c) 2024-05-21 21:20:37.889 3713-3713 DEBUG pid-3713 E failed to read process info: failed to open /proc/3699 2024-05-21 21:20:37.916 3713-3713 DEBUG pid-3713 A *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Issue summary
My tablet emulator still run normally but automotive emulator not run. I using Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1

Is this keep happening even if you create new AVD?

Car watchdog service is responsible for managing car-specific functionalities in the emulator. It isn't running or configured correctly, preventing the emulator from accessing car-related features. Solution 1. Rebuild Automotive AVD 2. Check for Conflicting Software like Antivirus or other software might interfere with the emulator, if possible disable them temporarily and try again.

Sharing the steps creating avd and downloading system image.

Run Device Manager, move to automotive tab, select Automotive (1080p landscape)
Download System image
Wait for a while
Next button
Finish button
Run the emulator


I tested with android-studio-2023.3.1.19 linux version and confirmed the Automotive (1080p landscape) API33 emulator works without issue.

Android Studio Info

Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 6.6.15-2rodete2-amd64
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 128
Current Desktop: GNOME



ro.build.fingerprint of avd system image

[google/sdk_gcar_x86_64/emulator_car64_x86_64:13/TAG1.230812.001.D2/11755969:userdebug/dev-keys]

Please refer to the attached screenshots.
automotive-emulator-embedded
automotive-emulator-standalone
